# Using multiple constraints in a JSON query

Tags: c#, arrays, json

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            JObject jObject = JObject.Load(new JsonTextReader(File.OpenText("categories.json")));
            JArray resources = (JArray)jObject["ResourceCategories"];
            foreach (var CategoryType in resources.Where(obj => obj["CategoryID"].Value<string>() == "food") && (obj["GameVersion"].Value<string>() == "1"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(CategoryType);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I can only match one criteria `foreach (var CategoryType in resources.Where(obj => obj["CategoryID"].Value<string>() == "food"))` When I try to add the second as in the code above I get an error. How can I pass multiple constraints?

Comment: What happens when u use multiple constraints? Whats the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you closed the where clause too soon. Try below code. Worked for me.

```
foreach (var CategoryType in resources.Where(obj => obj["CategoryID"].Value<string>() == "food" && obj["GameVersion"].Value<string>() == "1"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(CategoryType);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, yes a simple typo.

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the predicate to the `where` statement with the parentheses after `... == "food"` so the other constraint is not a part of the selection in `where`.

Guessing that this is a mistype and you meant to have this

```
foreach (var CategoryType in resources.Where(obj => (obj["CategoryID"].Value<string>() == "food") && (obj["GameVersion"].Value<string>() == "1")))
```